# Kony Middleware mandatory for RESTful service calls?

Tags: mobile, temenos-quantum

Referring to this question:
[Is it mandatory to use Kony middleware for Kony application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850234/is-it-mandatory-to-use-kony-middleware-for-kony-application)

One of the response said that if the response is in JSON, then it is not necessary to go through the middleware.

However, if the services are RESTful but not in JSON (say in XML), does it still need to be routed through the Middleware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to consume webservice without the middleware the response should be in JSON, otherwise its not going to work (and the middleware became mandatory in this scenario)

Answer (score 0):

We can call or consume the services without using the middleware using the HTTPRequest API

```
var request = new kony.net.HttpRequest();
request.onReadyStateChange = callbackHandler1;
request.open(constants.HTTP_METHOD_GET, service_url);
request.send();
```